# simple close button function featherlight don't work jquery

Tags: jquery, button

I have a close button in a Modal lightbox View. But if you click on the button the window does not close.

Here my HTML Code:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1">lösche</a>


<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
    <h2>Delete Item</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <strong>Are you Sure?</strong><br>
           blubblub?
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">

       <a href="#" class="btn btn_gray no text_none" id="close_button">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn_red text_none">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here my jQuery code:

```
// Close Button featherlight

jQuery('#close_button').click(function(){
    console.log("test");
    jQuery('.featherlight').click();
});
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin seems to generate element on the fly (cloning without bound datas???), you need then to delegate event, e.g:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#close_button',function(){
    console.log("test");
    jQuery('.featherlight').click();
});
```

[SEE jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/7/)